# Custom view attributes not being found on pre 5.0 devices

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi I just stumble upon in something kind of weird.

I'm creating a custom View which has elevation and state list animator tags that will only work with 5.0 android devices. Also the view uses his own custom attributes. The XML looks something like

```
<CustomView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/
    android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_anim"
    fab:fabCenterDrawable="@drawable/fab_icons" />
```

If I run the application using a 5.0 device, everything woks as expected; but if I do the same with a < 5.0 device the last custom attribute is not being read!
So, trying to figure it out what is happening I printed all the attributes from the attribute set. The results for 5.0 device is the following:

```
background : @2130837555 of type String
layout_width : @2131230769 of type String
layout_height : @2131230769 of type String
layout_centerInParent : true of type String
elevation : @2131230766 of type String
stateListAnimator : @2131034112 of type String
fabCenterDrawable : @2130837558 of type String
```

And for the pre 5.0 devices and getting the following:

```
background : @2130837555 of type String
layout_width : @2131230769 of type String
layout_height : @2131230769 of type String
layout_centerInParent : true of type String
stateListAnimator : @2131034112 of type String
```

As it can be seen, the elevation value is not being read, because that tag only works with the 5.0 SDK, but the weird part is that the custom attribute is missing also!

After spending some time trying to figure it out the problem I just go ahead and do a simple test, I pushed the lollipop only tags to the end of the XML, so the XML now look like this:

```
<CustiomView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_size"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_background"
    fab:fabCenterDrawable="@drawable/fab_icons"
    android:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/fab_anim" />
```

And now everything works fine in all android versions...

Is this an expected behavior, or is just a bug? Or do I need to provide a extra piece of logic in order to prevent this kind of behavior.

Comment: This is an AAPT bug that's been fixed internally for the next release. In the meantime, the workaround that you've discovered is the best approach.

Comment: @alanv Perfect, so I'll stick to my workaround. And thanks for the notice.